# iOS Remote Notifiction handle app active case

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I have enabled remote notification with background modes.

hence I need to handle a case in which app is in foreground and notification arrives. So only when user taps on Notification are it should perform an action like open another view.

But in my case, it happens automatically.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("APNS didReceive with fetchCompletionHandler: \(userInfo)")

    switch application.applicationState {
    case .background, .inactive:
        PushNotificationManager.shared.handle(info: userInfo)
    case .active:
   // TODO THIS ACTION SHOULD ONLY TRIGGER WHEN USER TAP NOTIFICATION
        PushNotificationManager.shared.handle(info: userInfo)
    }
    completionHandler(.newData)
}
```

How I can make this possible???

**NOTE:** NOT A DUPLICATE QUESTION AS THEY HAVE NOT SPECIFIED THIS SITUATION EXACTLY

Comment: Why are you performing tasks on mere receiving of notification? You should put the deeplink logic in `application(:open:options:)` and `application(:continue:restorationHandler:)`

Comment: @thesummersign: Because i need to perform, i want user tap and do a certain action , and when notification is arrived only this method is called not any other.
and it is completely independent of deep linking, we don't have that type of flow right now.

Answer (score 0):

The method you're referring to will get called when a notification arrives, that'll be either when the app is background or foreground.

But that's not the case when the user taps on a notification.

You need to assign a delegate to `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate` and then implement this method — `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)`

```
class NotificationHandler: NSObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        Logger.log("didReceive notification: \(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")

        if response.actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier {
            let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
            // Process the user info —
        }

        completionHandler()
    }
}
// In `application(_ application:,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`
// Note this is for clarity - you'd need to keep a strong reference to the NotificationHandler() or will get deallocated immediately.
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = NotificationHandler()
```

Answer (score 0):

for me this method is called earlier

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    completionHandler(.newData)
}
```

because I haven't set delegate of **UNUserNotificationCenter** in AppDelegate.

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
```

As by **@Dimitris** suggestions I have added then it called

**willPresent** & **didReceive** APNS delegate methods (new delegate methods introduced in iOS 10)

Hence now i'm able to handle user tap action on APNS as on tap it trigger didReceive delegate method.